# How to get the current user in twig extension service [symfony2.8]

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to get the current `user` in my `NotificationExtension.php`. But the page become very slow to load and I also get this error:

> Error: Call to a member function getUser() on null

The error say that is impossible to get the current user, but i'm login.

**This is my service:**

```
notification:
  class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Twig\NotificationExtension
  arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@service_container', '@security.context']
  tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

**NotificationExtension :**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Twig;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Twig_Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class NotificationExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $container;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em,ContainerInterface $container, SecurityContext $context)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->doctrine = $container->get('doctrine');
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getGlobals()
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        return(array(

            'unreadMessagesCount' => $this->em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Notif')->findBy(
                    array(
                        'user' => $user,
                        'seen' => true
                    ),
                    array('date' => 'DESC')
                )));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'notification';
    }
}
```

**ADD:**

**service:**

```
notification:
  class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Twig\NotificationExtension
  arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager','@security.token_storage']
  tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

**get current user:**

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
}
```

Comment: Try with service `@security.token_storage` and access user as : `$this->user = ($tokenStorage->getToken()) ? $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() : null;`

Comment: I have the following error when i put your line in  `public function getGlobals()`.  `Notice: Undefined variable: tokenStorage`

Comment: I meant to change your `SecurityContext $context` with `$tokenStorage` in service definition as well as in class.

Comment: What you have will not work because the notification extension object is created early on during the request process, before the user has been authenticated and loaded.  What you need to do is add a function to get your user data and then call it from your twig template as needed.

Comment: That what i did. my service look like this : `arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@service_container','@security.token_storage']` and in my `public function __construct` i added this : `TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage`

Comment: @Cerad Do you have an example how can i do it ? I have tried to create a function but the count of unread message remain at 1.

Comment: Update your question with the function you tried.  Get the rid of the container nonsense.  Just inject the entity manager and the token storage.  It also seems a bit strange that you have seen = true when trying to find unread messages.

Comment: @Cerad i added in my question on top,  the service without the container and with a function that allow me to get the current user. I don't think my function is right.

Comment: Okay.  We are just spinning our wheels here.  Update your question to show your actual code because what you have is totally borked right now.  @Yonel's answer might get you there but I fear you will need to invest some time learning php oop.  Just take a break then come back and try to understand what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you for you help. I have tried with the answer of Yonel and it work as I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define instead a service as a global Twig variable:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        user_notification: '@app.user_notification'
```

The service class:

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/Globals/UserNotification.php

class UserNotification
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    // ...

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, ...)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        // ...
    }

    public function getUnreadMessages()
    {
        if (null === $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            return array();
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();

        // $unreadMessages = <DB query for get the unread messages from current user>

        return $unreadMessages;
    }
}
```

The service definition:

```
# app/config/config.yml

services:
    app.user_notification:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\Globals\UserNotification
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage', ...]
```

Finally, for all templates you can to use this service:

```
# foo.html.twig

{{ user_notification.unreadMessages|length }}
```

Whenever the global variable is accessed in the template, the service will be requested from the service container and you get access to that object.

---

More information http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in the userNotification this line `$user = $token->getUser();`  and this line return `$unreadMessages;` are undefined.

Comment: Yes, you should complete these lines, I show you only a tips to resolve the user issue.

Comment: Only you need to inject the entity manager service and make the query ;)

Comment: Thank so much for your help. It worked perfectly :) I'm a newbie sometimes simple things may be difficult for me , but i'm learning each day.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the username like that : app.user.username

If you want to check if the user is logged, you can use the is_granted twig function.

eg :

```
{% if is_granted("ROLE") %}
    Hi {{ app.user.username }}
{% endif %}
```